# Java with Web service Axis

Tags: java, web-services

I am new in Java Webservice, Please Let me know any one know abt Java webservice using Axis.

Thanks

Comment: Voted to close. This question is far too broad. Ask something more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Read [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Axis) first.

Answer (score 0):

@shyamu, before you go down the Axis path, I suggest you look at the following comparison between Axis and Spring WS at http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=105424

I don't know if you're familiar with Spring, but since you're new to web service as you mentioned, this might be a good time to give you options before you spend your precious time to something you might not like at the end.

I personally prefer Spring WS than Axis. And I just don't say that I prefer it, but rather I wanna share that knowledge as well. For Spring WS starters, you can look at http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-ws-tutorial-using-latest-200-rc2.html